# The getter 'latitude' was called on null. E/flutter ( 9972): Receiver: null E/flutter ( 9972): Tried calling: latitude

Tags: flutter, google-maps

I am trying to show latitude and longitude on a map. I am successfully getting latitude and longitude from previous page and pass to my map page, but i always get error on map screen. Latitude and longitude not works.

[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'latitude' was called on null.
E/flutter ( 9972): Receiver: null
E/flutter ( 9972): Tried calling: latitude

```
    import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
    import 'dart:async';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:geocoding/geocoding.dart';
    import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
    import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
    
    class MapsInfo extends StatefulWidget {
      String lati, longi, title;
      int myId;
    
      MapsInfo({Key key, this.title, this.myId, this.lati, this.longi})
          : super(key: key);
      @override
      _MapsInfoState createState() => _MapsInfoState();
    }
    
    class _MapsInfoState extends State<MapsInfo> {
      Completer<GoogleMapController> controller1;
    
      //static LatLng _center = LatLng(-15.4630239974464, 28.363397732282127);
      static LatLng _initialPosition;
      final Set<Marker> _markers = {};
      static LatLng _lastMapPosition = _initialPosition;
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        if (widget.myId == null) {
          _getUserLocation();
        } else {
          _initialPosition =
              LatLng(double.parse(widget.lati), double.parse(widget.longi));
        }
      }
    
      void _getUserLocation() async {
        Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
            desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
        List<Placemark> placemark =
            await placemarkFromCoordinates(position.latitude, position.longitude);
        setState(() {
          _initialPosition = LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);
          print('${placemark[0].name}');
        });
      }
    
      _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
        setState(() {
          controller1.complete(controller);
        });
      }
    
      MapType _currentMapType = MapType.normal;
    
      void _onMapTypeButtonPressed() {
        setState(() {
          _currentMapType = _currentMapType == MapType.normal
              ? MapType.satellite
              : MapType.normal;
        });
      }
    
      _onCameraMove(CameraPosition position) {
        _lastMapPosition = position.target;
      }
    
      _onAddMarkerButtonPressed() {
        setState(() {
          _markers.add(Marker(
              markerId: MarkerId(_lastMapPosition.toString()),
              position: _lastMapPosition,
              infoWindow: InfoWindow(
                  title: "Pizza Parlour",
                  snippet: "This is a snippet",
                  onTap: () {}),
              onTap: () {},
              icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker));
        });
      }
    
      Widget mapButton(Function function, Icon icon, Color color) {
        return RawMaterialButton(
          onPressed: function,
          child: icon,
          shape: new CircleBorder(),
          elevation: 2.0,
          fillColor: color,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
        );
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: _initialPosition == null
              ? Container(
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'loading map..',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'Avenir-Medium', color: Colors.grey[400]),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              : Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 60.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                  child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
                    GoogleMap(
                      markers: _markers,
                      mapType: _currentMapType,
                      initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                        target: _initialPosition,
                        zoom: 14.4746,
                      ),
                      onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
                      zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
                      onCameraMove: _onCameraMove,
                      myLocationEnabled: true,
                      compassEnabled: true,
                      myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
                    ),
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                      child: Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 50.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                          child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              mapButton(_onAddMarkerButtonPressed,
                                  Icon(Icons.add_location), Colors.blue),
                              // mapButton(
                              //     _onMapTypeButtonPressed,
                              //     Icon(
                              //       IconData(0xf473,
                              //           fontFamily: CupertinoIcons.iconFont,
                              //           fontPackage:
                              //               CupertinoIcons.iconFontPackage),
                              //     ),
                              //     Colors.green),
                            ],
                          )),
                    )
                  ]),
                ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Position could be null.
So, you can access the latitude with null operator "!" as

```
position!.latitude
```